# Contains in Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have to ensure that only certain cells are there in excel and not more or less than that. Even these header cell texts are pre-specified. Even different cell text also cannot be allowed in the application.

Then based on the headers, I have to put the data into a list.

What I am doing to convert my excel in dictionary is this :

```
var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

int headerCol = 2;

Dictionary<string, int> map = Enumerable
    .Range(ws.Dimension.Start.Column, 24 - ws.Dimension.Start.Column + 1)
    .ToDictionary(col => ws.Cells[headerCol, col].Value.ToString().Trim(), col => col);

for (int rw = 3; rw <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rw++)
{
    if (!ws.Cells[rw, 1, rw, 24].All(c => c.Value == null))
    {
        lgl.GroupMembershipUploadInputList.Add(new GroupMembershipUploadInput()
        {
            cnst_mstr_id = (ws.Cells[rw, map["Master Id"]].Value ?? (Object)"").ToString(),
            cnst_prefix_nm = (ws.Cells[rw, map["Prefix"]].Value ?? (Object)"").ToString(),
```

But now how would I make sure the dictionary map only contains these much specified string keys and not anything different than that, e.g. Master Id and Prefix - only these 2 and exactly these two.

In actuality there are 24 keys. Is there any shorthand code to check?

Comment: `map.Keys.All(k => new[] { "Master ID", "Prefix" }.Contains(k));`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Dictionary class contains a method called `ContainsKey()` that can be used to check for the existance of a key within the dictionary :

```
if(map.ContainsKey(key))
{
      // Do something
}
```

If you needed to check for the existence of multiple keys, you could store the keys that you needed to check for within a collection and then use a bit of LINQ to evaluate it :

```
// Keys to check for
var keys = new []{ "Master_Id", "Prefix" };
// Check if all of these keys exist
if(map.Keys.All(k => keys.Contains(k)) && map.Keys.Count() == keys.Count())
{
      // All of the keys are present in your collection
}
```

Alternatively, you could just check the intersection of the keys via the [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) method and ensure they match as well :

```
if(map.Keys.Intersect(keys).Count() == keys.Count())
{
       // Exactly every key is present
}
```

Comment: Your LINQ query checks to make sure all of the keys are in the map, but the OP wants to make sure that only those keys are in the map.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was more of a typo than anything, but dramatically makes a difference.

Comment: Why not add condition (map.Keys.Count() == keys.Count())? Jointly with your code it will also make sure that there are no extra keys in map.Keys

Comment: Except doesn't enforce the keys to be present at all, map.Keys could even be empty.

Comment: That's an excellent point, I'm actually going to remove it entirely as it doesn't read particularly well either.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want the two key sets to be equal, so you need two checks that they contain each other.

```
string[] keys = new[] { "Master Id", "Prefix" };
Dictionary<string, int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>();

bool check = keys.All(map.ContainsKey) && map.Keys.All(keys.Contains);
```